# LibreOffice icons missing from Unity task panel

Tags: 12.04, unity

After installing 12.04, I removed the LibreOffice icons from the left task panel to reduce clutter.  However, now when I start LibreOffice from the home button, the icons do not reappear in the launcher as a running program.  In addition, they don't appear in the ALT-TAB menu either.  All other applications (chrome, terminal, etc) seem to work fine.

Is there some way to restore the icons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply drag them from the dash onto the launcher. I have had this same issue with other programs (namely Gimp) where the program does not appear on the launcher or in alt-tab. It is a known bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/995916). The only way to get back to them is to either use SUPER+W (the super key is the Windows key, if you didn't know) or keep the shortcut on your launcher. According to the bug, it should have been fixed, so try updating too.

Comment: Thanks!  Your workaround works.  Looks like it's fixed in 5.12.0-ubuntu2 and I'm on 5.12.0-ubnutu1, so I should get a fix soon.

Comment: No problem. Just be patient, the real fix should come soon. If you feel my answer was deserving, please mark it as solved. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait, you can't mark an answer as accepted until after 15 minutes :)

Comment: I guess we're too quick.

Comment: I also hv the same problem, but when I drag the icon from the dash into the launcher, it stays there but it still doesnt work when I try to open another document.. its again the same thing, the document is there, but it doesnt show in the launcher (not even an arrow on the writer icon) and not in the alt-tab menu either..

Comment: @SwapnilNarendra - Please ask a new question. You will get much better help that way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding first LibreOffice Write to the panel by right-clicking on it. Then the open document icons also show up.