# no LibreOffice icon in applications bar

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LibreOffice icons missing from Unity task panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144151/libreoffice-icons-missing-from-unity-task-panel)

When opening a LibreOffice document, the icon appears briefly in the application-menu bar then disappears, letting no way to retrieve the window if minimized. Alt+Tab does not show the window either. BIG problem.

Config: Ubuntu 12.04, LibreOffice 3.5.4 (Same problem with 3.5.3).

Was OK with Ubuntu 11.10

I tried to select "KDE compatible" in CompizeConfig but did not help.