# no LibreOffice icon in taskbar when directly opening a document file

Tags: icons, libreoffice, cinnamon, taskbar, nemo

First, i don't think it's an duplicate of: 
[no LibreOffice icon in applications bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144202/no-libreoffice-icon-in-applications-bar)
and/or 
[LibreOffice icons missing from Unity task panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144151/libreoffice-icons-missing-from-unity-task-panel)

**I am using:**

- Ubuntu [15.04] with Cinnamon[2.8.0]-Desktop
- LibreOffice  [4.4.6.3]

### (UPDATE, I upgraded my system to:)

- Ubuntu [15.10] with Cinnamon[2.8.6]-Desktop
- LibreOffice  [5.0.2.2]

**My problem:**
When i double-click an `*.doc` or `*.xls` (or any other LO-) file (in Nemo<strike>[2.8.0]</strike> [2.8.6]),
LibreOffice opens and shows up the document, but with **no** TaskBar-Icon.

**However, [ALT-TAB] works and shows up all open (LibreOffice-)Windows!**

**But:**

When i start LibreOffice via `*.desktop` shortcut or 
via command-line (e.g:`libreoffice --calc`) the LibreOffice-Icon **is displayed/shown** in the taskbar.

Comment: You should probably report those as bugs. http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: 1. Is the file represented in another icon (or an "iconles"  icon), or not *at all*  2. Did you edit or create a `.desktop` file

Comment: 1. the (document) file has an regular (Word/Excel) icon (from my icon set) 2. LibreOffice created the desktop-file (i made no edits) [i have also no problems when starting LO via command-line] There is absolute NO ICON, when opening the document directly (via DoubleClick)

Comment: @Ben Ah, I mean in the launcher (/taskbar)

Comment: I updated my system and LO (see the question), but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using `kazam` software to record but i couldn't find out what was the problem, so i came up with another solution...
I used the 'Hot Corners' to switch between windows...

1. From taskbar open the 'System Settings'
   [image]
2. Now click on 'Hot Corners' to open the settings
   [image]
3. In here choose one of the Corners and set the event to 'Show all windows' and set the 'Icon visible' and 'Hover enable' to checked.

   [image]

Now When you take your cursor to the corner, you'll see all open windows and you can easily switch to each of them.
[image]

Example :

[image]

Comment: thanks for your support, but as i pointed out: **ALT-TAB works and shows all open (LibreOffice-)Windows**, so your Hot-Corners-Solution is not needed (in my case).